Unable to find module in theta_sketch.mjs for theta_sketch_int64
I have generated the theta_sketch.mjs file using make command and used the following script to create theta_sketch_int64 UDF.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/blob/master/udfs/community/theta_sketch_int64.sqlx
However, I am getting the following error while invoking the theta_sketch_int64 UDF in BigQuery.
TypeError: Module._clamp_lg_k is not a function at theta_sketch_test.theta_sketch_int64(INT64, INT64) line 56, columns 16-17
Looking for assistance to resolve this issue.
